# How to combine the default value, null value and the value of item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, haml, default-value

I have an argument year in my model. This parameter defaults to 0, if the parameter is not in a form that is inserted into the database 0 (not working with nil).
A text_field is rendered when necessary and is contained in the part.

```
.div-form-item
    = f.label :year, t('advert.form.year')
    = f.text_field :year, :value
```

How to set :value => "" or :value => nil if it rendered?

In current situation I see 0 in new form (when I want create new item), but I want see empty field.
The problem is that this form is also used to edit an item and need to set the value of an item.

Comment: `= f.text_field :year, :value => ''` maybe this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will display a blank field if the value is 0, but it will also submit that blank value if users did not add a year. So you'd need to handle that on form submission.

```
f.text_field(:year, :value => f.object.year.eql?(0) ? '' : f.object.year)
```